# Javascript pattern matching and expression evaluation logic

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript string which i want to evaluate as an expression and compare with values.

```
var stringExpression=">.5*{PropertyValue} + .2*{DesignValue}+ 2000 +{price}";
```

The values inside curly braces are of element id present in dom and the expression above is dynamic but the elements whose values i want to pick will always be present inside curly braces. I plan to pick these values using jquery. $("#PropertyValue").val(). Can somebody tell me how to do this evaluation in javascript post setting the values from dom and any ideas how to replace values, do i need to use split function or some regex can be used to achieve it.

You can also point me to any framework in javascript that can help in this regards.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution in the functional paradigm which reads quite nicely:

```
function value(tag)
{
    var key = tag.substr(1, tag.length - 2) //remove braces
    return document.getElementById(key)
}


function populate(template)
{
    var tagRegExp = /{.+?}/g
    var tags = template.match(tagRegExp)
    var values = tags.map(value)
    return template.split(tagRegExp).zip(values).join("")
}

var template=">.5*{PropertyValue} + .2*{DesignValue}+ 2000 +{price}"; 
console.log(populate(template))
```

This solution requires a `zip` method for array objects which can be implemented as in the following (unless it is already provided by a library).

```
Array.prototype.zip = function (other) {
    function zipOne(acc, x, i, a)
    {
        if (i < other.length) {
            if (i < a.length - 1) {
                return acc.concat([x, other[i]])
            } else {
                return acc.concat([x]).concat(other.slice(i))            
            }
        } else {
            return acc.concat([x])
        }
    }

    return this.reduce(zipOne, [])
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution was smooth as butter.

Comment: I changed the implementation of `zip` so that it doesn't modify its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str=">.5*{PropertyValue} + .2*{DesignValue}+ 2000 +{price}"; 

var regExp = /{(.*?)}/
var values = []
var match = str.match(regExp)
while (match != null) {
    var value = document.getElementById(match[1])
    str = str.replace(match[0], value)
    values.push(value)
    match = str.match(regExp)
}
```

Comment: Can i also get the values propertyValue, designvalue etc in the while loop you have mentioned. Thanks for the solution though.

Comment: Well, i have been able to resolve what i asked in my last question.

Comment: I have rewritten the solution now to handle the replacement value correctly ($1 cannot be used as an argument to getElementById).